# ¿Es posible usar imágenes guardas de un sistema de PHP que se encuentra en un Hosting desde una aplicación para escritorio en JAVA?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un sistema web en lenguaje PHP subido en un Hosting, ahora quiero hacer ese mismo sistema pero convertido en aplicación de escritorio lenguaje JAVA utilizando la misma base de datos.

Cuando creo usuarios en el sistema de PHP inserto las imágenes en una carpeta dentro del proyecto e inserto el nombre de la foto en una columna de la tabla usuario.

Pero ahora no se como obtener esas imágenes para mostrarlas en el proyecto de JAVA , e estado intentando ingresar a la carpeta mediante una ruta  pero no me muestra la imagen y cuando uso la ruta en el buscador de Google si me muestra la imagen , alguien sabe a que se debe? necesito permisos? si ese es el caso cuales serian?  si la forma en al que quiero obtenerla no es posible que podría hacer para que los dos sistema usen las misma imágenes?

Este es el código que e estado usando para poder ingresar a la carpeta :

```
String urlImagen = "https://www.ruta.pe/sistema-PHP/assets/images/uploads/img_usuarios/foto-luis.jpg";

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(urlImagen);
this.jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
this.jLabel1.setText("");
```

**Cuando ingreso la ruta en Google me muestra la imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Al iniciar Java no me muestra nada**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta convertir el string en objeto URL de la siguiente forma

```
URL urlImagen = new URL("https://www.ruta.pe/sistema-PHP/assets/images/uploads/img_usuarios/foto-luis.jpg";);
imagen = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imagen); 
this.jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
this.jLabel1.setText("");
```

Como **nota**, yo no pude ver la imagen, ya que me marca un problema de DNS, no sé si lo tuyo sea un virtualhost y por ahí pueda ir también el problema.